# What is the number of simple, undirected graphs where each node's degree is 2?

Tags: graph-theory

I know that the answer to this question is given using the following regression formula:
$$f(n)=(n-1)f(n-1)+\binom {n-1}{2}f(n-3)$$

The first part of the right-hand side is true when a node is added somewhere between two nodes, however I'm having trouble understanding why the second part is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively, such a graph consists of a finite number of disjoint circles (over $n$ vertices alltogether).  The second term denotes the case where you open up a new circle with 3 vertices, one of them is $n$ and the other 2 can be chosen out of the set $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$, hence the ${n-1\choose 2}$.  The remaining vertices can be connected to fit the premise in $f(n-3)$ ways.

Also note that you're not counting the isomorphism classes but the concrete number of graphs over the vertex set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ which fit your premise.